# cannot derive from sealed type 'ResourceDictionary',Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I want to make a Resourcedictionary that will then used in another page(Will call mergedwith to add it to the resourceDictionary of a page as per this page.https://xamarinhelp.com/merged-dictionaries-xamarin-forms/) but i keep getting the error.
'Styledictionary': cannot derive from sealed type 'ResourceDictionary'.

I am using Xamarin version 4.1.2.18
I simply added a xaml page from crossplatform. my.xaml looks like

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CrossPlatform.Styles.StylesDictionary">
  <Style x:Key="EnumButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackGroundColor" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
  </Style>

  </ResourceDictionary >
```

and the .xaml.cs looks like

```
namespace CrossPlatform.Styles
{
    public partial class StylesDictionary 
    {
        public StylesDictionary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ResourceDictionary become public after [`Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.107`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.0.107) so you need to update your `Xamarin.forms`. You can find detailed changeset from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/commits/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ResourceDictionary.cs).

Comment: Hey, I am actually using version 4.1.2.18

Comment: Hi, I looked more closesly and you were right. i do not have the latest nuget packet for xamarin.forms.Thank you very much